# Is it possible to generate build.ninja for Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, ninja, compilation-database

I have been using ninja build for some projects. And it is very convenient to generate a compilation database file with `ninja -t compdb`. This file can be used in Visual Studio Code for accurate symbol resolution.

So is it possible to generate a `build.ninja` and then the compilation database for the Linux kernel?

### ADD 1 - 6:54 PM 12/5/2021

I did some search and found some related links. Just note them here for now.

https://dev.to/wataash/create-compilation-database-compilecommandsjson-for-netbsd-kernel-source-3c3n

https://github.com/vitkyrka/kninja